# React: Lerna React hooks error on monorepo

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with using Lerna.
My folders structure are like shown below:

```
packages
  myapp
  shared
```

myapp represents a create-react-app structure and shared contains some functions that is returning as below:

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

function Hello(){
 return (
  <Card>
    This is a test
  </Card>
 )
}
```

When I use material ui components instead of DIV's i get error that says:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

But when I use div and other html elements it works fine.

Maybe I got this error because of babel loader? I don't know what to do and how to setup things.

Comment: I already have this issue and was because I had two versions of React in the same monorepo... Dont know if is the same, but ensure that you just have the React of the root

Comment: How can I make that? Because i must have React import in shared components and in my react app folder

Comment: The problem is not on the import, is on where your import are searching, he should look for react at root. If you are using Lerna + Yarn Workspaces, your node_modules of the package should not contain the react folder inside

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you have multiple versions of React installed, and more than one get's bundled into the app.

Try to add this to your webpack config:

```
config.resolve.alias = {
    'react': path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'node_modules', 'react'), // Adjust for your path to root node_modules
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Like tbergq said it's because there are multiple versions of React installed. Adding this to the individual package's package.json seems to work for me:

```json
  "alias": {
    "react": "./node_modules/react"
  },
```

I am using Parcel so the webpack config wouldn't work for me. Also, in the root package.json, I use `nohoist`, although I'm not sure if it's necessary now as I'm using alias above.

```json
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "./packages",
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**"
    ]
  }
```

I know this is an old question, but just wanted to share in case someone is Googling this. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62126594/2280866