# What is the correct way to include React in both an application and a private library? (React Invalid Hook Call warning from duplicate React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parceljs

I have a sort of a "monorepo", one big project consisting of a few smaller projects that use React.

I'm trying to break these up into three separate repositories, lets call them `Core`, `Application1`, and `Application2`

The `Core` is a dependency of both applications, and the `Core` depends on React, because it defines some React component classes.  The applications both also use React.

When I tried to build this all together (using Parcel bundler), I am getting a final bundle which at runtime gives the [Invalid Hook Call](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) warning in one (but not both) of the applications.

On that page (or in the error message), it says that the error could be caused by one o these:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

I have checked that #1 is not true, and I'm not even using hooks in any way that I am aware of, so the problem is seems to be multiple versions of React.

I gathered from reading about this that it was a mistake for my `Core` library to declare React as a dependency, and that it should instead declare it in `peerDependencies`.  That made the Application stop giving the error, but it also made my Core library start having a bunch of Typescript errors and failing to be able to run the unit tests (which rely on React, using Jest/Enzyme to render and validate DOM).

Since specifying React in `peerDependencies` caused it not to be installed in the `node_modules` of `Core`, I decided that I should probably include React in both the `peerDependencies` and the `devDependencies` of `Core`.  That fixes the Core library again but breaks the Application.

I'm not really sure of the following:

- Why one of my applications fail due to duplicate React copies and the other doesn't, since they seem pretty symmetrical to each other.
- Why, even though I only specify React in `peerDependencies` and `devDepenencies` in `Core` I still would get a duplicate copy of React in the dependent application
- Whether the method used to bring `Core` in to the application has any bearing on this.  (one method I'm trying is package.json I specify core as a "file:../" style of URL.  Another alternative is to use "yarn link", or possibly to do both of these, and I'm not sure whether this has any effect on what ends up in `node_modules` underneath the application folder or on what gets bundled)

What is the right way to include React in both an Application and a library, in such a way that both of those projects have React available but there does not end up being duplicates in the Application causing this hook error (or, just taking up extra space).

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @Keith sometimes yes, and sometimes no.  Have the same problem regardless of OS

Comment: "Whether the method used to bring Core in to the application has any bearing on this" <- yes, it does. How are you importing Core into your other applications? Are you publishing it somewhere and adding it as a dependency in the other apps? What do your package.json files look like? (you could post those here)

Comment: @jared as mentioned, the Applications are using a package.json relative file reference to bring in the Core, e.g., `"my-core-library" : "file:../my-core-library"`.  I'm doing this because I don't intend to publish the core package to npm.  But I want to be able to develop both the Core and the Application at the same time, and simply using the relative file reference is problematic because it's a copy, and so the Application does not continually get the Core source changes, which is why I have also been using `yarn link`, which allows Core changes to propagate to the application immediately

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

I found the following issue helpful: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14257

Various different suggestions were made in the comments of ways to solve this problem, either by `npm link` or `yarn link`ing the react library from the library to the application, or vice versa.  Those all seemed promising, since the idea is to make sure that all of the different references to React are actually pointing to the same place.  Unfortunately none of those worked for me. (e.g. the answers by JerryGreen and Kas in that issue)

Another user, dcecile, suggested using webpack's `alias` feature, but I'm not using webpack.

```
resolve: {
    alias: { react: require.resolve("react") }
},
```

Parcel has a similar `alias` feature but can't be used in quite the same way because it's used in the package.json file so things like `require.resolve` can't be called like they are in webpack's js config file.

I ended up finding a way to use Parcel's `alias` feature to do what I wanted, based on another example from https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx/issues/64 from user jaredpalmer.  In my situation, I'm adding this to the application's package.json, and it appears to get rid of the duplication problem and the "Invalid Hook Call" error:

```
 "alias": {
    "react": "../my-core-library/node_modules/react",
  },
```